# How to include acronyms from separate .tex file in main project file in LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex

I am working on my thesis and I have a separate .tex file for acronyms.

The **Acronym.tex** file content is as follows:

```
    \chapter{Acronym}

    \newacronym{TOC}{TOC}{Total Ownership Cost}

    \newacronym{CTMC}{CTMC}{Continuous Time Markov Chain}
```

In the **main.tex** file I used the package glossary:

```
\usepackage[xindy,acronym]{glossaries}
```

Then in the same file after including the List of Tables I called the Acronym.tex as

```
\input{acronym}
```

The page is included but empty:

[image]

Inside my text in different chapters the acronym worked when I used `\gls{}` command to insert them within the text.

For example, `\gls{TOC}` produced

> ( **Total Ownership Cost (COT)**  )

So my issue is only to show a list of all acronyms in front of the thesis after the list of tables.

When I deleted the glossary package and only used `\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}` the acronyms showed but in bad formatting:

[image]

This is the content of main.tex (not everything but enough to be a working example):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, onecolumn, openright]{book}

\begin{document}

\include{acronym}

When considering the \gls{TOC}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting ?

Comment: To print the list of acronyms with the `glossaries` package, you need the command `\printglossaries`. Place it where you want your list of acronyms to appear. This command will also automatically add the chapter/section name for you, so no need for `\chapter{Acronyms}`. You can of course customize this heading to suit your needs. Also, don't forget to add `\makeglossaries` to the preamble of your document.